# python list comprehensive if else

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

hi I want to use list comprehension to create a list of integers with the followings:

If it is an int leave it unchanged.
If it is an str convert it to an int.
Otherwise None.

Example:

```
func([(1, "48")])     # [(1, 48)]
func([(1, "0xf")]))   # [(1, 15)]
func([(1, "junk")]))  # None
func([([3], 4)]))     # None
```

here my code so far:

```
def func(iterable):
    if not (isinstance(x, int) and isinstance(x, str)):
        return None
return [x if isinstance(x, int) else int(x) if x.isdigit() for x in iterable]
```

when I run its broken right over for x in iterable (invalid syntax), still cant figure it out. 
can you please show me where I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `0` as base for `int` conversion and python will try to deduce the base. This only accepts strings, so we can use `str`. The try-except returns `None` when a conversion is not possible:

```
def func(iterable):
    try:
        return [int(str(x), 0) for x in iterable]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Your test cases are not very correct, check these:

```
print func([1, "48"])    # [1, 48]
print func([1, "0xf"])   # [1, 15]
print func([1, "junk"])  # None
print func([[3], 4])     # None
```

Comment: Thank so much :) but I have one more question, we are given an iterable of tuples which is [(1,"48")] then yield the tuples with elements are int (or can be converted to int), none otherwise. how are we supposed to do this?

Comment: Please catch precise exception, in this case ValueError.